# How do I decide what goes into the entity and what goes into the port in Hexagonal Architecture?

Tags: hexagonal-architecture

Usually, when I create a domain entity (for example a bank account) it includes things like `account id` and `starting balance`.

But I have seen some Hexagonal projects that also have functions like `calculateBalance` or `createAccount`.

I usually put these functions it ports though.

My question is, what are the rules for deciding where to put the domain specific functions between the ports and domain entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, domain entities should contain domain-specific functions that operate on properties or make calculations based on properties without the need for external data to be involved in decision making, for example:

```
class Account {
  withdraw(amount: number) {
    const newBalance = this.balance - amount;
    if (newBalance < 0) {
      throw Error("Withdrawal denied");
    }
    this.balance = newBalance;
  }
  calculateFutureBalance() {
    return this.balance - this.futureDebits;
  }
}
class WithdrawUseCase {
  execute(input) {
    // TODO: run the following code under a single unit-of-work
    const account = this.accountRepository.get(input.accountId);
    account.withdraw(input.amount);
    this.accountRepository.save(account);
  }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to make business decisions based on external data, you should create that logical unit as a function inside a service ("domain service") and have your port call this function. For example:

```
class AccountService {
  centralBankService: CentralBankService; // Assumed to be initialized
  makeAccountGolden(account: Account) {
    const hasCredit = this.centralBankService.hasCredit(this);
    if (!hasCredit) {
      throw Error("No credit from central bank");
    }
    account.makeGolden();
  }
}
class MakeAccountGoldenUseCase {
  execute(input) {
    // TODO: run the following code under a single unit-of-work
    const account = this.accountRepository.get(input.accountId);
    this.accountService.makeAccountGolden(account);
    this.accountRepository.save(account);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is extremely clear and exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you desertech! In the case of withdraw, is it a domain service that calls this function too? As in, the withdraw skips the port and appears in the service when needed?

Comment: In the withdraw use-case domain logic is completely encapsulated within entity, hence no need for domain-service. I added more code for clarification.